# How to Cache a dynamic site with 1,890,000 pages and host them on AWS statically

Tags: javascript, php, oracle, caching, amazon-web-services

I've built a dynamic site that provides open medical data in an easy to read format with graphs. The site is hosted on a hand built server in my garage and is running on a Comcast connection. It has served over 3,000,000 people since it came online and I really need to find a better way provide it as it's become very stressful trying to keep it up and continue to develop it. It's built on PHP and JS with Apache and has an Oracle back end at the moment. The data itself is only updated every quarter so if I could host the site statically somehow on AWS it could handle the attention it's been getting. I've already learned a lot about proper caching from other questions here but my case seems like a larger jump than most. Anyone have experience with this type of move?

Thanks!
- DC

Comment: host content on s3, cache with cloudfront or akamai or [insert cdn here]? You might want to provide a more specific question.

Answer (score 1):

Your easiest route is to simply route everything through cloudfront. Cloudfront can use your current system as an origin and cache your content around the world on its endpoints.

You will need to configure the caching settings to reflect your update schedule, but if your content isn't really dynamic, this is probably the easiest way to go.

There are other options of course, but that depends on more information.